# how to get the current page endpoint

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

i need to get the endpoint of active tab in myaccount page from WooCommerce
for example:
$currnt_endpoint="the active tab endpoint(for example edit-account)";

Comment: https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/is_wc_endpoint_url/

Comment: Thank you @Jacob Petattie